# SQL Server: Import and Export CSV

Tags: sql-server, database, csv, sql-server-2000

I am working on SQL Server 2000. As you know, there is an application that's shows query results (Query Analyzer) The data is shown there, on a grid, and you can save that grid in a csv file. That's great.

Now, I want to INSERT those csv values into a Table. Does SQL Server provide any method?? And I mean, automatic or semi-automatic methods (like when you read an Excel from Query Analyzer).
Because, for example, with a Bulk insert I can accomplish that but, it involves a lot of work.

I am considering developing an application that does that (maybe in python) But, I don't want to if anything else already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need CSV exports/imports, I'd use BCP. It's much faster, it's easier to use for those requirements (at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

You can look at using [DTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933484%28SQL.80%29.aspx) <strike>[SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)</strike> to do this.

DTS is what you will want to use for SQL Server 2000 (as the comments below suggest).

I believe you can also copy paste directly from a spreadsheet into a table if you're not trying to do anything too fancy.  I haven't done this in a while so you'll have to double check.

Comment: Actually in SQL Server 2000, they were called DTS - Data Transformation Services

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the heads up guys.  Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know how to import from Excel, you can open the .CSV file(s) in Excel and save them as .xls once the conversion is done.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a csv file at all, why not simply insert the results of your selct statement? Assume the select you used to build the csv was :

```
select a.field1, b.field2 
from anothertable a
join yetanothertable b on a.myid = b.myid
```

why not just do:

```
insert mytable (field1, field2)
select a.field1, b.field2 
from anothertable a
join yetanothertable b on a.myid = b.myid
```

If you really have a csv file to import, you can do so using the import wizard if it is a one-time deal or a DTS package if it is a repeatable process you want to do on a regular schedule.

Comment: Because it is not the case. What I need is export the data. Many reasons. In fact, I do what you suggested, in other cases (when I need to) even from two different servers (using opendatasource) But, what I ask for is another thing.